# Embedding User's Most Recent YouTube Videos On iOS

Tags: ios, youtube, youtube-api

I am attempting to show a YouTube channels most recent uploads. I want the most recent to be at the top, with the 2nd most recent below and so on so you can scroll through the uploads.

My problem, however, is i can only manage to embed the most recent video and that autoplays the next upload, which I don't want to happen.

How can i embed or somehow display a channels most recent uploads?

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will do a [channels->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) to get user's [uploads playlistId](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads).

With that id, you will get each [videoId](http://snippet.resourceId.videoId) with [playlistItems->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) call.

Then by using [Iframe player](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference), you can create players with each videoId also [disabling autoplay](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Autoplay_and_scripted_playback).

Comment: still a bit confused. What link would i use for the video embedded in the web view? or are you telling me to do it through the API, im slightly clueless on that, could you give me the code if it is that?